extend 9v 500mA to 7 meters
I want to use the cat6 cable to extend 9v 500mA to 7 meters, what is the method without losing current and voltage, the transformer must stay at home due to weather conditions of heat and rain?

What's the copper AWG and how much voltage drop you allow? Because in real world wire, there is always some drop.

This is what PoE is designed for.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Given the limited and fixed resources, you don't have many options.  You don't say if the 9 V is AC or DC.  Let's assume DC.  One option is to place a boost converter at the house end, and a buck regulator at the remote end.  With a constant load, increasing the voltage on the lines lowers the current through the lines.  This lowers the voltage drop caused by wire resistance.  Of course, neither converter is 100% efficient so there will be power loss through the system, but that can be compensated for with the buck regulator at the far end.
BUT - there is a test you can perform with zero additional parts, converters, etc.  Cat 6 cable has 8 conductors.  Parallel 4 of them for the + and 4 for the -, and measure the resulting voltage across the load.  It might be good enough.
Noise pickup probably is not an issue, but you can mitigate that a small amount.  For each color pair there is one wire with a long color stripe and short white stripe, and another wire with a long white stripe and a short color stripe.  Connect the 4 wires with the long white stripes to one polarity, and the 4 wires with the long color stripes to the other polarity.

( Cat 6 cable has 8 conductors. Parallel 4 of them for the + and 4 for the -, and measure the resulting voltage across the load. It might be good enough.)                                                               This is a good idea in order to reduce resistance, I have already worked on this idea, (5V; 500mA) for the computer using the cat6 cable known for its quality, where I extended the cat6 cable for a distance of 5 meters for the ALFA network card. So I connected two VCC+ lines, two GND lines, one line for D+, and one line for D- and the results were very good.

Good enough to be the answer? Also. please update your question with the voltage detail - AC or DC?
